# how to create circle or rectangle automatically from lat long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have following code and I open new page with lat long parameter. How to create circle from lat long because I want create automatically rectangle or circle from latlong please see below image I want like this,  but my code does not show  circle hope anyone help me. thanks developers

```
var myParam = location.search.split('lat=')[1]
var res = myParam.split("&lng=");
var lati = res[0];
var longi = res[1];

_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
});


var citymap = {
    chicago: {
        center: {
            lat: lati,
            lng: longi
        },
        population: 4856
    }
};
for (var city in citymap) {
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: _map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    });

}
```

[I want like this editable rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phDZd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with the code posted is the error from the API: `InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`.  You are retrieving the coordinates from a string, they need to be numbers, you can use `parseFloat` to convert them to numbers:

```
var myParam = location.search.split('lat=')[1]
var res = myParam.split("&lng=");
var lati = parseFloat(res[0]);
var longi = parseFloat(res[1]);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c26L766h/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var myParamLoc = "lat=42&lng=-72";
var myParam = myParamLoc.split('lat=')[1];
//var myParam = location.search.split('lat=')[1]
var res = myParam.split("&lng=");
var lati = parseFloat(res[0]);
var longi = parseFloat(res[1]);

_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true
});


var citymap = {
  chicago: {
    center: {
      lat: lati,
      lng: longi
    },
    population: 4856
  }
};
for (var city in citymap) {
  var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: _map,
    center: citymap[city].center,
    radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100,
    editable: true
  });
  _map.fitBounds(cityCircle.getBounds());
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The important bit is getting the bounds for the rectangle correct. You don't really say how you want to do that - you've got a single coordinate for the centre of Chicago.  The circle you're setting its sized based on population.  Maybe we can use that circle's bounds to work out the same for the rectangle.

```
var rectangle = google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: _map,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#A3E8FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    bounds: cityCircle.getBounds(),
    editable: true
});
```

Comment: i want draw rectangle or circle automatically but my code does not show

Comment: @Addikhan sorry I left off the fillOpacity property which maybe was why it didn't show